# My cron works when given * in hh, but doesnt when I give a numeric value

Tags: cron

This works:
`* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/vlc --play-and-exit /home/tc/Music/test.ogg`

(Plays every minute)

This works:
`30 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/vlc --play-and-exit /home/tc/Music/test.ogg`

(Plays every hour at 30th minute)

This doesn't work:
`30 08 * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/vlc --play-and-exit /home/tc/Music/test.ogg`

(Doesn't play at 8:30 am, what am I doing wrong here?)

I am trying this on ElementaryOS.

I tried to put * in all except command column and it works.
But when I specified the exact hour when I want it to run, it failed.
But when I specified the exact minute with * in hours column, it works.
This is really confusing, I did not find anything in the syslog file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the BIOS time is not synced to your system time.

Boot your system and press F2 (or Del key, based on what machine you are using), go to BIOS and check the time it's showing there. If it's not matching with your time, then change it to match to your system time (usually by pressing the F5 or F6 keys).

Once it's matched, save the settings and reboot the machine.

Now your cron should work as usual.

So basically, the cron is working on your BIOS time and not what you see on your task bar.